# File Structure: Requiring Sub-Modules in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, require, node-modules

I have the following Node.js module/npm package:

```
|- dist/
|- - requirejs/
|- - - [stuff in amd pattern ...]
|- - node/
|- - - index.js
|- - - submodules/
|- - - - submodule1.js
|- - - - [submodule2.js etc.]
|- package.json
|- README.md
```

I can require `dist/node/index.js` via the module name (because I set it as the main entry-point file in package.json) like so:

```
var myModule = require('myModule');
```

I would like to require the submodule (as in AMD pattern) by doing so:

```
var mySubmodule = require('myModule/submodules/submodule1');
```

This throws an error in Node.js. The problem is, that Node.js requires the main file from its `dist/node/` subdirectory but still keeps the modules root as the working directory.

Assuming the following structure would be present:

```
|- dist/
|- - node/
|- - - index.js
|- submodules/
|- - submodule1.js
|- package.json
|- README.md
```

Now doing `require('myModule/submodules/submodule1')` would work.

**NOW THE QUESTION:** Is there any setting/config to set the "module namespace" or working directory to the directory where the main file is in, or do I really need to put the submodules folder into the project root, to make it accessible without doing `require('myModule/dist/node/submodules/submodule1')`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer: You should either directly use the second directory structure you proposed (`/myModule/submodules/`) or add some kind of API to your main exports (*index.js*) to quickly get the desired module.

While you can technically call `require('myModule/some/complex/path')`, the Node.js / npm packages standard is to rely on the unique interface provided by `require('myModule')`.

```
// /dist/node/index.js
var path = require('path');
exports.require = function (name) {
  return require(path.join(__dirname, name));
};
```

Then in your app:

```
var myModule = require('myModule');
var submodule1 = myModule.require('submodules/submodule1');
```

Comment: `require('myModule')` does not return a module object (or maybe at least not anymore)

Comment: At least `require('fs/promises')` has now become a canonical "my/complex/path"

Answer (score 0):

You now can do something like this using the [`exports` feature](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_packages) of Node.